# How to open csv files from different directories, do a calculation and open next files to do the same

Tags: python, csv, directory

I have two different directories with csv-files, which are build like "xxx_1.csv" and "yyy_1.csv". I want to read that files, do a calculation with them, then iterate further through the directories and read "xxx_2.csv" and "yyy_2.csv", do the calculation and so on.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: We'll need a lot more information than that, unfortunately. Be sure to read how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use python os to walk through your directory(you can use the specific dir as the root of your path of walk on dir). Then for each files you can detect if the file is a csv or not then do something you want to it

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

# traverse root directory, and list directories as dirs and files as files
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("<relative dir target such as: ./myname>"):
    # DO something here
    for filename in files:
        if ".csv" in filename:
            doReadAndCalculationOn(filename)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it's not clear enough what my issue is, my fault.
I think the for loop is needed here, like u wrote is the right way. But in the next step I want to read csv's xxx_1 and yyy_1 and do a calculation. The question is I think, how to combine the for loop (searching through 2 different folders) and combining csv's with same index in the name.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest for you to read your CSV files as pandas dataframes and do calculations on the dataframes. In case you didn't know, pandas is an extremely common library used for vectorized calculations on dataframes.

It doesn't matter if they're in different directories, you can specify that in the argument later.

For example, imagine your directories looked like this:

```html
\-- root
  |-- main.py
  \-- folder1
    |-- xxx_1.csv
    |-- yyy_1.csv
  \-- folder2
    |-- xxx_2.csv
    |-- yyy_2.csv
  \-- folderx
    |-- xxx_x.csv
    |-- yyy_x.csv
```

And so on. All you have to do now is import pandas, and read those csvs into separate dataframes. It wouldn't be very efficient to read those csvs every iteration and make a new dataframe every time, so it's probably easier for you to make them into separate, readable dataframes with easy to understand names.

```
import pandas as pd

df1_x = pd.read_csv("./folder1/xxx_1.csv")
df1_y = pd.read_csv("./folder1/yyy_1.csv")

df2_x = pd.read_csv("./folder2/xxx_2.csv")
df2_y = pd.read_csv("./folder2/yyy_2.csv")

dfx_x = pd.read_csv("./folderx/xxx_x.csv")
dfx_y = pd.read_csv("./folderx/yyy_x.csv")
```

And so forth... I dunno what you plan to do with those dataframes, but in case you want to concatenate the x and y dataframes, it's as easy as:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1_x, df1_y])
df2 = pd.concat([df2_x, df2_y])
dfx = pd.concat([dfx_x, dfx_y])
```

You get the picture.

EDIT: fran na jaya's answer is probably better than mine